# Is preferable to remove the code not necessary to answer the question, when there is an answer that refers the code that would be removed?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

In [My for statement keeps repeating even though I set a limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654332/my-for-statement-keeps-repeating-even-though-i-set-a-limit) [part of the code written by the OP has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12654332/2), but there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654352/225647) that is telling the OP something was wrong in that part too.

Is it correct to remove the not necessary code, in this case?
Should the question be changed to contain the original code (even if better formatted), or should the answer be changed not to reference the code that is not in the new revision of the question?

Comment: I'd put part back part of what was removed, just enough to show two of the strange `if`s.

Comment: I would say that the edit made was inappropriate, no matter how innocuous it might seem. It changed the question too much.

Comment: I agree with @Bart. If you are not the OP you should *never* make substantial changes to code in a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, if a problem in the code is unrelated to the problem that the question addresses, anything addressing the other problem should be in a comment, not an answer. That's because addressing issues unrelated to the main problem in the question does not answer the question.

I also think that edits like that, if they substantially change the meaning of the question, should not happen in the first place.